# Node HTTP POST Request to Netatmo

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, http-post

I'm trying to do a http POST request to my Netatmo weatherstation's cloud using NodeJS. It really needs to be http post and not use the node's 'request' module, because I indend to use it in AWS Lambda and that module is currently not supported there.

Whatever I try, I get the dreaded {"error":"invalid_request"} with result 400.. I am at a loss as to what the problem is.

Here's my snippet:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var https = require('https');  
function getNetatmoData(callback, cardTitle){
        var sessionAttributes = {};

        var shouldEndSession = false;
        cardTitle = "Welcome";
        var speechOutput =""; 
        var repromptText ="";

        console.log("sending request to netatmo...")

        var payload = querystring.stringify({
            'grant_type'    : 'password',
            'client_id'     : clientId,
            'client_secret' : clientSecret,
            'username'      : userId,
            'password'      : pass,
            'scope'         : 'read_station'
      });

        var options = {
            host: 'api.netatmo.net',
            path: '/oauth2/token',
            method: 'POST',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(payload)

        };

        //console.log('making request with data: ',options);

        var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
                res.setEncoding('utf8');

                 console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
                 console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    console.log("body: " + chunk);

                });

                res.on('error', function (chunk) {
                    console.log('Error: '+chunk);
                });

                res.on('end', function() {

                    speechOutput = "Request successfuly processed."
                    console.log(speechOutput);
                    repromptText = ""
                    //callback(sessionAttributes, buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
                });

            });

            req.on('error', function(e){console.log('error: '+e)});
            req.write(payload);

            req.end();
    }
```

Here's Cloud9's console log:

```
Debugger listening on port 15454
sending request to netatmo...
statusCode:  400
headers:  { server: 'nginx',
  date: 'Tue, 24 Nov 2015 19:30:25 GMT',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'content-length': '27',
  connection: 'close',
  'cache-control': 'no-store',
  'access-control-allow-origin': '*' }
body: {"error":"invalid_request"}
Request successfuly processed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aarrgh.. I oversaw something. Apparently, the headers need to be set in the options when making the request. It is in the headers variable that the Content-Type and Content-Length are set.

Without further adue, here is the correct working of the options variable :

```
var options = {
    host: 'api.netatmo.net',
    path: '/oauth2/token',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(payload)
    }

};
```